# QString select lines range

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qstring

I have a huge QString (a big logfile), how do I select line 10 to line 20 for instance?

Something like

```
QString tenLines = bigHugeQstring.linesRange(10,20);
```

is it possible?

Comment: Why aren't you reading the file into an array of strings to begin with?

Comment: Do you mean a QStringList array for each \n? That's an idea, let me see if I can do it

Comment: QString::split('\n'). But I'd avoid reading the huge data alltogether, if you're only interested in a couple lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A QStringList was a better solution